# How to set a dynamic component within a child component in React from the parent component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, reactjs

I have a parent component that pulls in a child component, that pulls in another child component. I want to be able to set what that child's child component is from the top parent. Cannot figure out how to do that. Here is some code to demonstrate what I am trying to do:

```
var TopParent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="topParent">
                <Child componentVariable="BottomChild">
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="child">
                <{this.props.componentVariable} />  // this should pull in a component based on what is passed from TopParent
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var BottomChild = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="bottomChild">
                I am the bottom child. I should be able to be swapped out from TopParent.
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Additionally, once I figure out how to do this, how do I make sure that Child requires the correct file for the BottomChild component?

Comment: Why don't you render your BottomChild inside your parent as a child of your child? And include it in your child through `this.props.children'? That way, your parent needs to know which BottomChild to render, but your intermediate child does not necessarily need to know. And direct child does not need to require it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use actual references, instead of strings; after all, when you render a component like `<Child />` manually, *it's* a reference, too.

```
var TopParent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="topParent">
                <Child componentVariable={BottomChild} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var Component = this.props.componentVariable; // make sure the var is capitalized
        return (
            <div className="child">
                <Component />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var BottomChild = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="bottomChild">
                I am the bottom child. I should be able to be swapped out from TopParent.
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

However, in many cases, it makes sense to allow the component [to *completely* control the contents of the child](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html):

```
var TopParent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="topParent">
                <Child>
                    <BottomChild />
                </Child>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        // `this.props.children` is the *contents* of the `Child` component
        // as specified in the JSX of `TopParent`
        return (
            <div className="child">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var BottomChild = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="bottomChild">
                I am the bottom child. I should be able to be swapped out from TopParent.
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```